# Updating a table with the columns of another

Tags: oracle11g

Relatively new to Oracle.  I am trying to replace the columns of one table with the columns of another. Here is my code:

```
update ems.ptnaddress p
set (p.ptnid, p.address1,p.address2, p.address3,p.address4) = 
(select p2.ptnid, p2.address1,p2.address2, p2.address3,p2.address4
from tempptnaddress p2 
where p.ptnid = p2.ptnid);
```

I am getting the error :

SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Any ideas of what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your tempptnaddress table has more than one row for at least some of the ptnid values and Oracle isn't going to pick which one of those rows to use to do the update for you. :)

For example, if I have table1 as

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
1       ONE     ENG
1       UNO     SPA
2       TWO     ENG
3       THREE   ENG
4       FOUR    ENG
4       CUATRO  SPA
```

and table2 as

```
COL1    COL2
1
2
3
4
```

and try and update TABLE2.COL2 using something like:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1)
```

what value in column TABLE1.COL2 should it use for 1 and 4? Oracle won't guess for us and that's when you get the ORA-01427.

It might be as easy as just picking one arbitrarily like:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col2 AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

but you probably want to put in some proper logic there like:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET col2 = (SELECT t1.col2 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col3 = 'ENG')
```

In your case, you need to get it so that the subquery in your update only returns one row per ptnid.

If you run this:

```
SELECT ptnid, COUNT(*) 
FROM tempptnaddress
GROUP BY ptnid 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

it will show you what ptnids that have more than one row in tempptnaddress. The trick will be to find out why there is more than one row per ptnid and how to pick the right one to use for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

UPDATE (SELECT p.ptnid ptnid1,p.address1 Addressnew1, p.address2 p.address3 p.address4 Addressnew4,p.ptnid ptnid2, p.address1 Addressold1, p.address2  p.address3 Addressold3, p.address4 Addressold4 FROM ems.ptnaddress p,tempptnaddress p2 WHERE p.ptnid = p2.ptnid) SET     ptnid1 = ptnid2,Addressnew1 = Addressold1, Addressnew2 = Addressold2,Addressnew3 = Addressold3,Addressnew4 = Addressold4